# MappingFacebook JSON response to POJO

Tags: android, json, gson

I am making an API call to Facebook and receiving the following Json object:

```
{"first_name":"FirstName",
"last_name":"LastName",
"email":"email@email.com",
"picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":true,"url":"pictureUrl"}},"id":"12345"}
```

Instead of deserializing the object manually, I am currently using `Gson` for it, like this:

```
FacebookProfileModel facebookProfileModel = new Gson().fromJson(object.toString(), FacebookProfileModel.class);
```

Here's how my POJO looks like:

```
  @SerializedName("first_name")
    String mFirstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    String mLastName;
    @SerializedName("email")
    String mEmail;
    @SerializedName("url")
    String mUrl;
```

Obviously, I am receiving all the values except for the url, since the value is in 2 Json objects: `picture` and `data`. I guess one possible solution but not the best would be to create the `Picture` object within the Facebook Model and then the `Data` object within the `Picture` object but feels bad creating 2 more pojos for a String. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no annotation based solution for this. However, the custom de-serializer would resolve this problem.

**Custom Deserializer:-**

```
public class FacebookProfileModelDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<FacebookProfileModel> {

    @Override
    public FacebookProfileModel deserialize(JsonElement paramJsonElement, Type paramType,
            JsonDeserializationContext paramJsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        String url = paramJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("picture").getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsJsonObject()
                .get("url").getAsString();

        FacebookProfileModel facebookProfileModel = new Gson().fromJson(paramJsonElement.getAsJsonObject(),
                FacebookProfileModel.class);
        facebookProfileModel.setmUrl(url);

        return facebookProfileModel;
    }

}
```

**Main method:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonString = "{\"first_name\":\"FirstName\",\"last_name\":\"LastName\",\"email\":\"email@email.com\",\"picture\":{\"data\":{\"is_silhouette\":true,\"url\":\"pictureUrl\"}},\"id\":\"12345\"}";      
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(FacebookProfileModel.class, new FacebookProfileModelDeserializer())
            .create();

    FacebookProfileModel faceBookProfileModel = gson.fromJson(jsonString, FacebookProfileModel.class);
    System.out.println(faceBookProfileModel.toString());

}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. It is indeed a good solution that I am currently using for similar things, I ended up creating 2 POJOs since I might end up expanding the POJOs at some point, due to more functionality. I'll accept and upvote the solution, since it is a good one.